# DirectX 10 Shader Pass Descriptor corruption

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, directx-10

Good afternoon everyone.

I've got a strange issue that I just can't seem to figure out.

In the following code segment

```
m_technique->GetPassByIndex(0)->GetDesc(&passDesc);

result = device->CreateInputLayout(polygonLayout,numElements,passDesc.pIAInputSignature,passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize,&m_layout);
```

the Direct X Debug output gives the following:

```
First-chance exception at 0x753D37C3 (kernel32.dll) in GameTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access     violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.
First-chance exception at 0x75B44B32 (KernelBase.dll) in GameTest.exe: 0x0000087A (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x0083E214, 0x0083D64C).
D3D11 CORRUPTION: ID3D10Device::CreateInputLayout: Third parameter is corrupt. [ MISCELLANEOUS CORRUPTION #15: CORRUPTED_PARAMETER3]
```

A few things that I am unsure about. In the last line I see D3D11 CORRUPTION, but I only use D3D10 headers and libraries.
I am working in Visual Studio 2012, and I have the Windows 8 SDK installed, so that may cause problems.

I'm not sure how to proceed and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled all the exceptions that the debugger could be throwing at you, or are you debugging your third or fourth access violation downstream from the point in time when things went south? (In the Debug->Exceptions Menu, did you enable all the break-when-an-exception-is option? All "Thrown" checkboxes checked?)

Comment: What is the information that you are passing in? Are any of the info null? Please show more code. I use the CubeRenderer.cpp file as a basis for creating input layouts, and no problems there.

Comment: Sorry guys, I know it's been ages, but this project fell by the wayside.
I didn't manage to get it sorted out per sè, but after a re-install of Windows 8 and all relevant SDK's I didn't run into this again.

I suspect that somewhere along the line something failed and I missed that, and passed in a null object.
Thanks for the assist.